# Vuejs .vue file: dynamic less import

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, less

I have a Vue app composed of several standard `.vue` files like this:

```
<template>
    <h1>My App</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        data () {
            return {
                cssTheme: 'default-theme'
            };
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="less">
    @import "assets/constants";

    html, body {
        color: @color-ui-text;
    }
</style>
```

In my `assets/constants.less` file I have defined many css variables to be used by *less* (colours, fonts and so on).

I want to give my app a serie of graphical "themes" that can be changed dynamically.

Given the variable `cssTheme` that I can read / set / change from the interface (and set it to strings like "green-theme", "vintage-theme", "default-theme"), how can I import and apply on the fly the appropriate *less* file into the `<style>` part of the `.vue` file? For instance, the user selects the "green-theme" and I want to switch the default imported file `@import "assets/constants";` to `@import "assets/constants-green";` where, for example, `@color-ui-text;` is set to dark green instead of the standard black.

Comment: I don't know if what you're asking is even possible, as the less is bundled and transpiled to css when you build, so you don't have any control over it at runtime. A simple way to achieve the same result is to just set a different class on the root element of your app/component depending on the theme that is set, and write theme specific rules targeting those selectors.

Answer (score -2):

If you use vue cli, you can use something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
          @import "assets/constants";
        `
      }
    }
  }
};
```

It will automatically add `@import "assets/constants";` in each sass file

Note: i use sass in example

more about this you can find here:
[loaderoptions](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-loaderoptions)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how this makes the imported assets selectable at run time

Comment: It isn't possible to use less/sass in runtime(for production), so you need to create different build to use different variables. 
For runtime i think you have only one way: css variables, but not shure about you target browsers. https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20var